# Disable paste image screenshot in jodit-react

Tags: jodit

I take a screenshot and paste to editor. This make storage is very big. How to disable paste image from clipboard to editor in jodit-react? I'm using jodit-react version 1.0.66.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const Example = ({}) => {
    const editor = useRef(null)
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')

    const config = {
        readonly: false // all options from https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/
    }

    return (
        <JoditEditor
                ref={editor}
                value={content}
                config={config}
                tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
        onBlur={newContent => setContent(newContent)} // preferred to use only this option to update the content for performance reasons
        onChange={newContent => {}}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**use the following option**

uploader: {
url: 'none'
},